# C++ How to convert string, which has string and numeric, into int or long

Tags: c++, string, atoi

I'm trying to convert a string variable, which contains alphabetic and numeric values, into an int variable.

```
string argument = "100km";
int i = atoi(argument.c_str());
cout<<i<<endl;
```

I've confirmed that `i` has an `int` of `100` and `km` is omitted.
However, if I enter `2147483648km`, which is over that range of `int`, `i` will have `-2147483648`.

[According to this page,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx) `int` is supposed to be able to have

> –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

So, I thought that this error came from the range of `int`, but the same error happens even when `atoi` is replaced by `atol` and `int` is replaced by `unsigned long`, which can have a much larger value. In other words, replacing int with long doesn't fix this error.

Chances are that I need to come up with an alternative way to convert this kind of string (i.e. string of "______km" into an int variable).

Comment: According to the page that you linked, `long` also has the range `–2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647` (on that platform)...

Comment: data type limits aside, I would use sscanf for this type of string parsing not atoi/atol. It's much more versatile.

Comment: Thank you all very much. Using `atoll` and `long long` seems to be the most suitable choice for my case, but other opinions are highly appreciated and informative too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type ranges from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)'s site can show you what Visual C++ compilers use. 
This may vary, see 6502's answer covering that.

Moreover, `atol` returns a `long`, so if you give it a `unsigned long` you're going to get a long in return.

Since C++11, you are able to use `atoll` which returns a `long long`, otherwise see the other answers using `stoi, stol, stoll`.

Answer (score 4):

In some compilers `int` is not "much less" than long, and indeed they're equal.

The only guarantee the standard gives you is that a `long` is never **smaller** than an `int`.

A simple solution would be to use `atof` instead that uses `double`s that on most platforms is a 64-bit IEE754 double-precision number that is able to represent all integers exactly up to a magnitude of 2<sup>53</sup> that is `9,007,199,254,740,992`.

Comment: Thanks for quoting the standard on `long` never being less than `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The size and range of the basic integer types depends on the compiler. On 32-bit platforms just about all compilers only have 32-bit `int` and `long` types. On 64-bit platforms the Visual Studio compiler *still* have 32-bit `int` and `long` while e.g. GCC have 32-bit `int` and 64-bit `long`.

If you want a larger type then you need `long long` which currently is 64 bits on all platforms and compilers (though it don't have to be).

Also, you should switch to [`stoi`, `stol` and `stoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (or their [unsigned variants](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul)) instead of `atoi`.

---

If you want to know the actual limits, sizes and ranges of a type, you should use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

Answer (score 0):

By using `strtol` you can achieve what you are looking for:

```
    string argument = "2147483648km";
    char *end;
    std::cout<<strtol(static_cast<const char *> (argument.c_str()),&end,10);
```

Depends on the size , you can prefer `stol`,`stoll` or `stoi`. More details are available here : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::stringstream`.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        std::stringstream ss { "2147483648km" };
        int n;
        string s;

        if (!(ss >> n ))
        {
                std::cout << "cannot convert \n";
        }
        else
        {
                ss >> s ;
                std::cout << n << " " << s << "\n";
        }
}
```

And you can even abstract the whole thing

```
struct Distance
{
    string unit; 
    int distance;

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Distance &d)
    {
         return in >> distance >> unit;
    }

};

std::stringstream ss { "331104km" };
Distance dst;
ss >> dst;
```